# "tried so far" vs. "so far tried"

Tags: word-order

These two sound quite different, and the second form even sounds more sophisticated, but is there any real difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have tried three strategies so far.
>
> I have so far tried three strategies.

The two are equivalent.

Think of "so far" as acting as an adverb. Substitute *now* and you can say:

> I have tried three strategies now.
>
> I have now tried three strategies.

Same difference.

But if you are following it with a list, I would suggest you use the latter construction.

> I have now tried three strategies: studying my rivals, cultivating new friends, and bribing public officials.

That way you put the noun that represents the list in apposition to the list itself.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but be aware of the (slightly obtuse) alternative reading, in the sense 'a trying experience':

> You can only be **tried so far** before you lose your temper

or, the other way

> He was **so far tried**, he decided to kill her

Comment: The last sentence is a run-on sentence.